# Joomla 2.5 how to set active menu on navigation bar kunena

Tags: joomla, navigation, forum

When I'm using Kunena on my site I have problems on the navigation bar.

Whenever I'm in a Kunena "page" the navigation is not showing the FORUM as active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around will be to change the active with java script or jquery

add this script to your index template

```
<script> 
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var isForumActive = <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/forum") !== false){ echo "true"; } else echo "false";?>;
if(isForumActive){    
   j(".item120").addClass("active");
}
</script>
```

You will need to change the id (120) with your menu id and be sure that the alias is the correct.

you need jquery as well....

Comment: that code assumes that his menu item will have id 120, which is very wrong. it also assumes link to his forum will be `/forum`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating all Kunena menu items as sub-menu items of the Forum menu item in the main menu and using [split menus](http://docs.joomla.org/Split_menus).